# How long does Trello store data for?

Tags: trello

I am working on a bunch of projects and there's every possibility that in a year I'll need to search for an archived item so I need to know if it will still be there.

How long are the archived items in Trello stored for?

Answer (score 3):

As long as Trello service is up and running. They are not deleting anything that you didn't explicitly deleted (if there is such option).